# Angular js page doesn't refresh after post

Tags: angularjs, http-post, page-refresh

Hi I am new to AngularJS. I have a page with a form that I post items on a list or queue as it is called here. When I press submit, the object gets added to the queue. Then in the success method of the post I call the http get to populate the new queue object. But this doesn't get refreshed on the page as expected.

Here is my html:

```
<html>
<head>
{% block stylesheets %}
<link href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="{{ asset('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}"
    rel="stylesheet" />
{% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    {% block javascripts %}
    <script src="{{ asset('js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/angular.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
    {% endblock %}
    <script>

    </script>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div ng-app="myApp">
                {{ '{{ formData }}' }}
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h1>New Customer</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
                                <form ng-submit="processForm()">
                                    <div class="wrap">{% include 'queue/services.html.twig'
                                        %} {% include 'queue/details.html.twig' %}</div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2"></div>

                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h1>The Queue</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body" ng-controller="myCtrl"
                            ng-init="readQueue()">
                            <ul>
                                <li ng-repeat="x in queueList">{{ '{{ x.type}}' }} {{'{{
                                    x.name }}'}} {{ '{{ x.service }}' }}</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
      app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.processForm = function() {
            $http({
                method : 'POST',
                url : 'http://localhost/firmstep/web/app_dev.php/queue/add',
                data : $.param($scope.formData), 
                headers : {
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                }
            }).success(function(data) {
                console.log(data);

                if (!data.success) {
                } else {
                    $scope.readQueue();
                }
            });
        },
        $scope.formData = {};
        $scope.queueList = {};
        $scope.services = [ {
            "0" : "Housing",
        }, {
            "1" : "Benefits",
        }, {
            "2" : "Council Tax",
        }, {
            "3" : "Fly-tipping",
        }, {
            "4" : "Missed Bin"
        } ],

        $scope.readQueue = function() {
            $http.get("http://localhost/firmstep/web/app_dev.php/queue/read").then(
                    function(response) {
                        $scope.queueList = response.data;
                        $scope.$apply();
                    });
        }

    });
```

Comment: If it isn't being refreshed, the most plausible explanations is that the post was not successful (and the success callback is thus not called), or that the `data.success `is falsy (and $scope.readQueue() is thus not called) or that the backend service responded with the same data as before. Use your debugger and your network dev tools to find out.

Comment: But wait, there is another explanation: you have two myCtrl instances in the page. One submits the form, and the other displays the queue. You're refreshing the queue inside the controller that processes the form, but does not display the queue. So the other controller still uses its own, original queue.

Comment: It works when i put the response div inside the original controller as you have suggested! Thank you.

Comment: Instead of  $scope.$apply(); will use the $scope.readQueue(); it will be work.

Answer (score 0):

You must add **$timeout** into your controller so as to force the page to refresh after the success method is reached. Below answer might help you.

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http,$timeout) {
    $scope.processForm = function() {

            $http({
                method : 'POST',
                url : 'http://localhost/firmstep/web/app_dev.php/queue/add',
                data : $.param($scope.formData), 
                headers : {
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                }
            }).success(function(data) {
                $timeout(function() {
                    console.log(data);

                    if (!data.success) {
                    } else {
                        $scope.readQueue();
                    }
                }, 3000);
            });

    },
    $scope.formData = {};
    $scope.queueList = {};
    $scope.services = [ {
        "0" : "Housing",
    }, {
        "1" : "Benefits",
    }, {
        "2" : "Council Tax",
    }, {
        "3" : "Fly-tipping",
    }, {
        "4" : "Missed Bin"
    } ],

    $scope.readQueue = function() {
        $http.get("http://localhost/firmstep/web/app_dev.php/queue/read").then(
                function(response) {
                    $scope.queueList = response.data;
                    $scope.$apply();
                });
    }

});
```